# Why can't I seem to iteratively populate a sql table in python pymysql?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Im taking a file train.csv, trying to iterate over it and create a new sql table. I'm getting a primary key error IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'trip2.PRIMARY'"). Is there a better way to create and fill a table? I'm using a jupyter notebook

```
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
import tqdm
import json

import csv


reader = csv.DictReader(open("train.csv"), delimiter = ",")
reader.fieldnames


conn = pymysql.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password = "",
        db='employees',
        )
cur = conn.cursor()


#10

try:
        cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS porto')
        cur.execute('USE porto')
        cur.execute('CREATE TABLE trip1(trip_id INT AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, taxi_id INT, start_year INT, start_month INT, start_day INT, start_hour INT, nb_points INT)')


        for trip_id, row in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(reader), total = N_ROWS):
            tim = dt.utcfromtimestamp(int(row['TIMESTAMP']))
            year = tim.year
            month = tim.month
            day = tim.day
            hour = tim.hour
            taxiid = int(row['TAXI_ID'])
            nb = len(json.loads(row['POLYLINE']))
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO trip1 VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6})'.format(trip_id, taxiid, year, month, day, hour, nb))

            conn.commit()
        
finally:
    print(cur.execute('SELECT * FROM trip1 LIMIT 10'))
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Ben If trip_id is an autoincrement field you shouldn't be trying to set it's value when inserting the other data. Try only inserting the data for the other fields.

Comment: Please share sample data from your file here.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove trip_id from insert statement since it's an identity column then you should be good to upload.

```
cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO trip1 VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})'.format(taxiid, year, month, day, hour, nb))
```